# Matrix and General Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In studying eigenvectors, I have stumbled across the following matrix :$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If I were to find the general solution for this matrix, how would I approach it?
Would $1$ still be a leading entry since its column is $0$? Would it be a free-variable?

The answer according to the text is $\bar v = t\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

EDIT: By "the general solution for this matrix," what OP really means is, "the general solution of the eigenvalue/eigenvector problem for this matrix."

Comment: Hint: $$\det \left( \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} \right)= 0$$

Comment: What do you mean by "the general solution for this matrix"? A matrix doesn't have a solution. The general solution of ... of what, exactly?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: ...of the eigenvector / eigenvalue problem.

Comment: OK. Can you edit that into the question? People shouldn't have to go through the comments to understand what the question is.

Comment: Never mind, I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

thise form of matrices have manyslotuions 
in thise case the system is 
x2=0 
and for x1 it can be any value as 0x1=0
thise is true for any value 
so we let x1=t ,
and x2 is already zero 
you will reach to the given solution
Note : yes 1 is a leading intery since the first column is zero

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the following you get:$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
v_2\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence: $\quad v_2*\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\quad$ is a solution for every $v_2$

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the eigenvalue problem of for the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, we need to calculate its characteristic polynomial which is $\det (A- \lambda I) = \lambda^2 - 0*1 = \lambda^2$. This tells us that the only root of the polynomial is $\lambda = 0$, i.e. only $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Hence, we need to solve the equation $(A - \lambda I )v = 0$, i.e. solve $Av= 0$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

which tells us that $0=0 $ and $v_2 = 0$, i.e. $v_1$ can be chosen freely and $v$ is of the form $v= t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$.

Since we are looking for the general form of the eigenvector, it's not a surprise that this vector is not uniquely determined. What's more interesting is the fact that we only have one 'free' parameter, and not two: Zero is a root of the characteristic polynomial with multiplicity $2$, but the eigenspace has only dimension one.

This kind of matrix is a so-called nilpotent matrix, and it shows some interesting facts of eigenvalues (namely that the algebraic and geometric multiplicity doesn't need to be the same).